# Comparison of room acoustics simulation techniques

Tags: acoustics, computational-physics, simulations

What is the state of the art technique for the numerical simulation of the propagation of a sound wave inside a room (room acoustics) regarding the time domain? I am specifically interested in the resulting sound field across the room.

Most likely this will be a Finite-Difference Time-Domain (FDTD) scheme. But i am unsure what is considered standard when it comes to simulation accuracy with things like advanced gridding techniques (adaptive mesh-refinement, boundary condition formulations) and modifications of the FDTD scheme (numerical dispersion, stability conditions, discretization schemes).

Hints to relevant papers are appreciated.

Comment: It depends what you want to output. Calculating the impulse response from a sound source to a receiver in the frequency domain using boundary elements, and then using convolution, might be much more efficient than FDTD.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I modified the question accordingly. Would this still be feasible when i want the sound field all across the room? Also performance is ambiguous. When it comes down to it i prefer accuracy over time complexity.